# How do I initialize a singleton spring bean when it is needed rather than on start up?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have a web application that uses several dao classes as singleton spring beans. My issue is that it takes a long time to initialize all of these beans and I would rather spread out that time to when the bean is actually needed (some might not even be used, depending on what the user does). Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set them to lazily initialize by adding [`lazy-init="true"`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init)

For example:

```
<bean id="lazy" class="com.foo.ExpensiveToCreateBean" lazy-init="true"/>
```

in bean definition xml

And in annotation based configuration

[`@Lazy(true)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html)

Comment: Although, depending on how long your application takes to start up, it's much more advisable for them to all be instantiated when the app starts. This will make sure that you detect problems sooner rather than later. If your context takes _that_ long to start, it may be a sign that you need to spread your application out

Comment: @user1637987 If your application context takes so long to initialize that it is becoming unbearable, it's likely a sign that your one application has _too many_ responsibilities. Although it's well out of the scope of this question, consider developing new code in _service oriented architecture_ such that you make remote calls to different logical systems (even if they're sitting on the same physical box) that perform different tasks